# Apply for a new visa when I still have a valid C visa but not enough days of stay?

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I have a valid c-type visa, multiple, 30 days, validity: 2/10/2014 - 2/1/2015 which I'd use this October for 12 days.

I plan to travel again entering Schengen 10/12/2014 and exit on 2/1/2015 . total 24 days.

Coincidentally, my current visa will still be valid until the day I exit Schengen. however I would have overstay the maximum 30 days stay of the visa.

TLS advise me to apply for a new visa, for the December trip to whichever is my main destination embassy. however, they are unclear of issuing the December visa if it is possible given old visa is still valid but not enough remaining days of stay?

Comment: TLS did not know the rules? I would ask to speak to someone else! Briefly you can apply for an extension if your current Schengen has unspent leave and you do not require the standard cooling off period.

Answer (score 1):

If your current visa will become invalid before your travel in December, you can apply for another visa or ask for your current visa to be extended as long as your 90 days of leave is not depleted.

It's preferred to go for a new visa because it enhances your history of successful applications.  When you submit your application, you can simultaneously ask for your current visa to be cancelled and provide a brief explanation.  It is not a complex process and does not involve any penalty in future applications.

Note that making a fresh application requires all of the same supporting evidence as your initial application.