# Apply for a new Schengen visa when you already have a used and valid National visa

Tags: visas, schengen

Similar questions have been asked here before:

[Apply for a new visa when I still have a valid C visa but not enough days of stay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37251/apply-for-a-new-visa-when-i-still-have-a-valid-c-visa-but-not-enough-days-of-sta)

[Can I have multiple Schengen visas for future travels in my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport)

But my example seems a bit different since I do have have a short Schengen visa before. I'm a Chinese citizen and have a used Spain long stay study visa (type D, multi-entry, stay 180 days) that's valid until Apr. 20th. What I want to know is if I can start **applying** for a short stay visa before the old one expires (i.e. Apr. 20th)? The two visas' valid date do not overlap: I want the new short stay visa to be valid from, say, May. 1st (which is just after the old one has expired).

The answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/traveling-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas) says yes. However, in that example while the old one is multi-entry like mine, it does not specify what the new visa type is. Is the example still valid if the old visa is long stay, multi entry but the new one is a short stay, single entry?

Comment: The source quoted in the previous question only pertains to short-stay visas. Legally, long-stay visas are very different, the Schengen visa code says very little about them.

Comment: @Relaxed The new visa is a short-stay Schengen visa, does the example apply?

Comment: I think it's OK but my point is that the Schengen regulations don't say anything about it one way or the other (i.e. it's not explicitly forbidden either). Or to say the same thing in a different way: It's probably allowed because it's not forbidden by the Schengen regulation but it's not what the quote in the previous answer was about (it was about getting two short-stay visas, one after the other).

Comment: I suggest editing the question and title to make it clear, as per my reply and @Relaxed response to it, to make a distinction between Schengen Visa and "National" Visa (D-Visa). They are not strictly the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, one **cannot** have simultaneously two valid Schengen visas. Any previous valid visas need to be revoked first.

Though it is rarely stated in explicit terms, if you visit any relevant embassy you will quickly find it out. I did a quick search and found several links. Take for example, [Embassy of Norway](http://www.norway.com.ua/studywork/Frequently-asked-questions/) says:

> A person cannot have two valid Schengen visas at the same time.

On a related note, they say:

> Can I apply both for C-visa and for a residence permit?
>
> **No.** There **cannot** be two applications at the same time for the same person. You will have to choose.

Comment: Since the OP would not get two C-visa (but one D-visa and one C-visa) nor apply for two visas at once (he or she already has a D-visa), this would suggest it is in fact possible…

Comment: Good point, a distinction needs to be made.